# How to turn AndroidManifest editable again

Tags: android, android-studio

I just merged my project with a branch. After i finished resolve conflict and checkout the master branch i got my AndroidManifest like this

[image: my pics]

How can i edit my AndroidManifest again? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue, it was because an update data in folder `.idea` (cache data) has been removed (i did this in order to avoid conflict between branches). It causes my Manifest unrecognized. What i did is, i try cleaning project then rebuild. After that i did `invalidate Caches/restart`. Now, everything back normal again. Thanks for your attention guys.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable read-only mode by any chance?

You can disable it by clicking on the lock on the bottom right.
[image]

Comment: It was in unlock state by default, i make it locked but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the text bar like the image bellow
[image]

Comment: i have faced same problem before with your solution, but in my case there is no tab below, maybe it need enable from someplace in configuration. I am looking for that yesterday

Comment: have you tried right click on any tag inside the manifest sources , then select "Go to declaration"

Comment: yes, when i clicked go to declaration noting happened then

Comment: It  sounds like you are trying to edit the generated Manifest in the gen/ folder instead.